# Java - Explanation for Judge's solution (RGB)

Tags: java, combinations, rgb

Recently I went to a programming competition in UF. This was one of the questions. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOKRa.jpg

This was the judge's solution: http://hastebin.com/unozolusiw.avrasm

This is the part I'm unsure about.

```
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0) {
                    sumR += rs[j];
                    sumG += gs[j];
                    sumB += bs[j];
                }
            }
```

I understand the sum adding part, and that N is the amount of cases, this part I don't understand:

```
if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0)
```

I know what & and << do, but I don't understand how that checks if you should add that to the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this generates all the binary numbers (from 0 to 2^N-1).

if the corresponding bits are non-zero then you select the colors to form a combination.

For example for 6=0110 you select bits 1 and 2 (from the right): if i and 
1 << j coinside in that bit you take the corresponding color (j).

i=0110 against j=0001, 0010, 0100, 1000

(There are at most 2^N possibilities of combinations of colors that's why pow=1 << N.)

--

ANDing i and 1 << j means if they both have any common 1-bits and checking against zero means that is true (they have some common 1-bits); since 1 << j can have only one non-zero bit (it's 1 shifted in different positions) i & (1 << j) can have at most one common bit: the color to choose.

You can try this code to see the combinations:

```
        int pow = 1 << 5;
        boolean works = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
            int sumR = 0;
            int sumG = 0;
            int sumB = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if((i & (1<<j)) !=0) System.out.println(i+" 22 "+j);
            System.out.println(i+" "+j);
            }
```